# How to display DMS in QGIS print composer?

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

Can we display degrees, minutes, seconds in QGIS Print Composer window instead of decimal degrees?

Is there any plugins available for that?

Answer (score 3):

For reference, this setting is found under the map item properties panel, "show grid" -> "draw coordinates" -> "format":

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to do that in a future version, as it has just been implemented:

```
commit d0b4fc17ea5d8a4a8006e2bc2bc6bd222a505f1d
Author: Marco Hugentobler <sourcepole.ch>
Date:   Thu Aug 9 17:23:35 2012 +0200

    [FEATURE]: possibility to show composer map grid coordinates in degree/minute/seconds
```

I doubt there is any c++ plugin out there already extending it.